# Is it possible to right-align only one component of a table header?

Tags: html, css, html-table, css-tables

I'm trying to right-align a Font-Awesome icon within a table heading, while the heading text is left-aligned:

[image]

I created the above screenshot using a hard-coded `margin-left` value on the `<i>` element, but this doesn't account for changing table widths.

Is it possible to right-align only part of a table's heading using CSS? Or do I need to set the `margin-left` dynamically based on the current table width?

Here's a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tuL2gmns/1/) showing CSS options I've tried, including `.text-right` and `.right` on the icon (which has no effect)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's an icon, why not just use a `float`?

```
.my-icon {
    display: block;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    float: right;
}
```

Don't forget to set `overflow: hidden;` on the container, of course.

Comment: In this case, the container is a table-cell. So it is already a block formatting context and therefore there's no need to use `overflow: hidden;`

Comment: @StephenLead In that case, will you accept this answer?

Comment: yep, just waiting the requisite 10 minutes - it's nice to have an answer come in so quickly that SO won't let you accept it yet :)

Comment: @StephenLead Heh, I'm glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

If you set the `th` to `position: relative`, you can use absolute positioning to get the desired effect.  Try something like:

http://jsfiddle.net/tuL2gmns/2/